# Async methods with and without async modifier

Tags: c#, async-await

What is the difference between methods `Add1()` and `Add2()`? Is there a difference at all? For all I know usage (as shown in method `UsageTest()`) is the same.

```
private async Task<int> Add1(int a, int b)
{
    return await Task.Run(
        () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                return a + b;
            });
}

private Task<int> Add2(int a, int b)
{
    return Task.Run(
        () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                return a + b;
            });
}

private async void UsageTest()
{
    int a = await Add1(1, 2);
    int b = await Add2(1, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Semantically, they are practically equivalent.

The main difference is that `Add1` has more overhead (for the `async` state machine).

There is also a smaller difference; `Add1` will marshal back to its original context while `Add2` will not. This can cause a deadlock if the calling code does not use `await`:

```
public void Button1_Click(..)
{
  Add1().Wait(); // deadlocks
  Add2().Wait(); // does not deadlock
}
```

I explain this deadlock situation in more detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [in a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Add1 will run synchronously until it encounters the await keyword.  In this case, that will not have an effect because the await keyword is at the beginning of the method.

To see the effect of this, you can insert a Thread.Sleep() method into the beginning of Add1 and Add2, and notice that the method marked async blocks before it returns.