# Misunderstanding of async/await functions

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I work with C#/VS2012/.Net4.0/Microsoft.Bcl.async NuGet package

After a previously question, I try to use async/await to avoid freezing UI. But each of my test is unsuccessfull.

The main function, which does a heavy work, was like this :

```
public bool PopulateTV()
{
  using (WaitingForm waitingForm=new WaitingForm())
  {
    waitingForm.Show();
    bool boolResult=DoHeavyWork(); //UI is freezing, waitingForm() doesn't show correctly
    return boolResult;
  }
}
```

A call to this function is like

```
if(!PopulateTV())
{
}
```

I try to implement the async/await

```
public async Task<bool> populateTV()
{
  using (WaitingForm waitingForm=new WaitingForm())
  {
    Task<bool> func=DoHeavyWork();
    bool boolResult=await func;
    return boolResult;
  }
}

public Task<bool> DoHeavyWork()
{
  //do the work
  return boolResult;
}
```

Of course, I get an error in `DoHeavyWork`, as I return a `bool` and not `Task<bool>`. So I change the `DoHeavyWork` function :

```
public async Task<bool> DoHeavyWork()
{
  //do the work
  return boolResult;
}
```

This time, no error, but a warning (I use a non english version of VS, so I translate the error/warning message) :

> This async method doesn't have an await operator, so it will execute
>   as synchronous.

It's only a warning, but why do I get this message ?

But it's not the big problem. When I call the parent method PopulateTV(), I want to return a bool value `(if(!PopulateTV()) ...`
And I get an error :

> ! operator can't be used
>   with 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'.

Of course. But `PopulateTV()` return a `bool` (`return boolResult;`), even if the method declaration use `Task<bool>`.

Where is my error ?

Answer (score 6):

You are not actually running your heavy-lifting code in a seperate thread - async does not automatically guarantee that.

Try something like `(await Task.Run(() => DoHeavyWork()));`

Comment: With the additional change of making `DoHeavyWork` return `bool` instead of `Task<bool>`.

Comment: I had thought that that was somewhat implied :D Love your website btw.

Answer (score 4):

[fk2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30805110/1025555) is correct, but you can avoid overhead and fragility by simply returning a `Task<bool>` directly:

```
public Task<bool> DoHeavyWork()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return HeavyWorkReturningBool();
    });
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987798/async-methods-w-and-w-o-async-modifier) for some more details.

---

However, as pointed out in the comments, this is not a clean solution. Offloading work to background threads to preserve UI responsiveness belongs to the UI code and not the API implementing the work. For a more modular solution you should implement it this way:

```
public async bool PopulateTV()
{
    using (var waitingForm = new WaitingForm())
    {
        waitingForm.Show();
        return await Task.Run(() => DoHeavyWork());
    }
}
```

`DoHeavyWork` remains a regular, synchronous Method:

```
public bool DoHeavyWork()
{
    var boolResult;
    //do the work
    return boolResult;
}
```

See the following blog posts for more information about this:

- [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)
- [Task.Run Etiquette and Proper Usage](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html)
- [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run for the Wrong Thing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html)
- [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)

Comment: Code that wraps the entire method body in a `Task.Run` is lying about its behavior; it's exposing an asynchronous API for a fake-asynchronous method. Wrapping the *call* to the method within `Task.Run` is more maintainable in the long term.

Comment: @StephenCleary, I don't understand what you mean with "fake-asynchronous". Isn't everything inside the lambda passed to `Task.Run()` being run asynchronously? I agree with your point on maintainability though. The intention was to wrap a single call, but I used the intermediate `result` variable to make it more explicit how `Task` is being used (i.e. inside the lambda one simply returns a value of the type indicated by the `Task`'s type parameter. I changed the code sample a little bit.

Comment: "Asynchronous" can mean a few different things. I call pushing work to a background thread "fake asynchronous", because all the code is doing is freeing up the current thread *by using another thread*. In contrast, "true asynchronous" code does not use any threads (one example is asynchronous I/O). In the op's case, there's (presumably) only synchronous work to do, so making the method signature async is misleading IMO. I have a longer description about [using `Task.Run` as a method implementation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) on my blog

Answer (score 1):

> But it's not the big problem. When I call the parent method
>   PopulateTV(), I want to return a bool value (if(!PopulateTV()) ... And
>   I get an error :

It's `if(!(await PopulateTV()))`. First wait for the result (bool) and later evaluate it.

In the other hand, your not that async method is equivalent to code it this way:

```
public Task<bool> DoHeavyWork()
{
  //do the work
  return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

`async/await` keywords are meant to work as syntactic sugar in order to re-write your [*task-based asynchronous pattern*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) code into a more readable one.

Actually, if your `DoHeavyWork` does something like this:

```
public async Task<bool> DoHeavyWork()
{
  await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(10000));

  return true;
}
```

...is almost the same as writing it this way:

```
    public Task<bool> DoHeavyWork()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew
        (
             () =>
             {
                  Thread.Sleep(10000);

                  return true;
             }
        )

    }
```

You need to understand that `async/await` is just a compiler feature to let you code elegant asynchronous code, but it doesn't mean that the async method must be asynchronous at all. It means that a `Task` instance can be awaited with `await` keyword.

That is, you can implement methods with asynchronous signatures (i.e. `Task MyMethod() { }`) but fake them returning a `Task` generated by a `TaskCompletionSource<T>`:

```
public Task<bool> DoHeavyWork()
{
  // No async operation here. This is just a fake!
  TaskCompletionSource<bool> completion = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
  completion.SetResult(true);

  return completion.Task;
}
```

...and this can be also simplified using `Task.FromResult<T>(T result)`, as you can check in some of this answer's code snippets.

### So, why I need to develop my APIs using task-based asynchronous pattern (TAP)?

Because the caller of your methods shouldn't need to know if the method is synchronous or asynchronous. Method's implementation will decide it, **but at the same time the caller can work asynchronously if the whole method is actually asynchronous**.

If you do the opposite (*sync methods*), your entire code flow will need to be changed if you decide to implement everything as asynchronous operations:

```
// I don't know if it's actually async or not, I don't care. The calling method
// decides it.
bool result = await DoWorkAsync();

// I know it's sync. So my code can become pure garbage if I need to make it
// synchronous since it can't be awaited and it doesn't return a Task instance!
bool result = DoWork();
```

Answer (score 0):

> But `PopulateTV()` return a bool (return boolResult;), even if the
>   method declaration use `Task<bool>`.

Wrong. `PopulateTV()` returns a `Task<bool>`

```
//        (return Type is here)
//           ||||||||||
//           vvvvvvvvvv
public async Task<bool> populateTV()
```

Just think of `return boolResult;` as being the return statement of the Task, not the method. To get the actual bool result, you need to await that Task:

```
if (!(await PopulateTV()))
```

Why are you getting a warning when you declare your method like this?

```
public async Task<bool> DoHeavyWork()
```

Because you are using `async` without `await`. You don't need the `async` keyword here. All `async` does is enable `await`, so if you don't use `await`, don't use `async`. You can just return a Task:

```
public Task<bool> DoHeavyWork()
{
    return Task.Run<bool>(() => 
        //do the heavy work
        return boolResult;
    );
}
```